# how to calculate the feature vectors approximately for storing in excel sheet?

Tags: excel, matlab, feature-extraction, glcm

In my GUI I am using this matlab code to store the values in excel sheet.This code is calculating the glcm six features.

```
function [Contrast,cor,ener,homo,Var,Entropy] = glcm_feature_extraction(I1)

Contrast = graycoprops(graycomatrix(rgb2gray(I1)),'Contrast')  
cor= graycoprops(graycomatrix(rgb2gray(I1)), 'Correlation')  
ener = graycoprops(graycomatrix(rgb2gray(I1)), 'Energy')  
homo = graycoprops(graycomatrix(rgb2gray(I1)), 'Homogeneity')  
img = double(I1);  
Var = var((img(:)))  
Entropy=entropy(I1)
```

Here suppose I get these values after calculation:

```
[0.603606103 : 0.785092239 : 0.271728411 : 0.855429408 :1889.578963 : 7.178149206]
```

But iI need only approx value like:

```
[0.6 : 0.7 : .2 ....]
```

How to modify this code to get this result?

Comment: You can round values up to `N` digits to the right of the decimal point by using `x_round = round(x, N)`. See the documentation for [`round`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) for more information.

Comment: I am getting error         Error using ==> round Too many input arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For example, lets consider Contrast=0.603606103

And you wanted to make approximately as 0.6 then use the following :

```
sprintf('%.1f',Contrast);
```

which should give you result exactly Contrast=0.6

Similarly do it for all remaining 5 variables.

Comment: I have used this y=sprintf('%.1f',Contrast); stored it in excel xlswrite('abc.xlsx',[y]); I am not getting the correct results as in excel file the result 0.6 is taking three cells to store itself rather than one  in excel file          thanks in advance